# What remedies would be possible/likely in a successful defamation suit?

Tags: united-states, defamation, court, remedies, mediation

This question is related to another one I asked recently: [Is it true that a suit of defamation could require "very little effort"?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/45559/867), so please review that one first -- thank you.

Let's say that someone brings a successful defamation suit.  What remedies are possible -- that is, what does the plaintiff stand to get out of winning such a lawsuit?  What remedies are likely?  I suppose monetary damages would be one possibility.  What others could be ordered?  What remedies tend to be ordered when a defamation suit is successful?  If mediation and negotiation might make sense in this context, please cover those thoroughly as well in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Defamation is a [tort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tort)<sup>1</sup>

It has all the remedies available to any tort. The typical ones sought are damages and an injunction requiring the defamer to issue an apology.

Of course, the parties are free to agree on any restitution they like in alternative dispute resolution.

<sup>1</sup>It can also be crime in many jurisdictions. either generally or in specific circumstances (e.g. blasphemy). Obviously, criminal sanctions apply to that sort of defamation but that's not what the OP is asking about.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101484/discussion-on-answer-by-dale-m-what-remedies-would-be-possible-likely-in-a-succe).